# HowTo: TFS --> check out C/C++ source files --> build libs through CMakeLists --> using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, tfs, module, cmake, libraries

The title explains my purpose and speaks out different problems i encountered trying to implement it:

1. Check out a TFS-Project with the Android Studio TFVC-Plugin was not very difficult - but i am not able to import the native code project as a module in my Android application. I tried to include it through settings.gradle and by new module without success.
2. I built the native (C) libraries using cmakelists.txt linking to the path i checked out. But it seems the dependencies are not set up 100% correct. I can include all files fine (for the compiler) but when i build i get the following error message: "'File_a.h' not found". Directory:
   AndroidStudioProjects
               | 
               + My_Android_Application 
               | 
               + TFVC_Workspace 
                          | 
                           + Lib_a 
                          |        | 
                          |        - **File_a.h** 
                          |        - File_b.h 
                          |        - File_b.c 
                          | 
                           + Lib_b depending on Lib_a 
                                   | 
                                   - File_c.h 
                                   - File_c.c 
                                   - File_d.h 
                                   - File_d.c
3. I tried to use different CMakeLists.txt according to [this](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/) guide, but since my TFS files are not stored in subdirectories to the CMakeLists in my Android Studio i got stuck.

I am not able to bring all the bricks together and i think theres (JUST a BIT) confusion in my hung up brain - therefore your help to figure out errors, wrong approaches, broken design, etc. is highly appreciated!

P.S. sorry so much for the bad Directory Tree - was not able to make it better. If you need more informations about files/structure please let me know!

**CMakeLists.txt** (located in C:/Users//AndroidStudioProjects/Android_Project/app)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(TFC_Path C:/Users/<user>/AndroidStudioProjects/TFVC/)
add_library( TFC_Lib_a 
             SHARED   
             ${TFC_Path}/Lib_a/File_a.h
             ${TFC_Path}/Lib_a/File_b.c                                   
             )
target_include_directories( TFC_Lib_a PUBLIC ${TFC_Path}/Interface_headers)


add_library( TFC_Lib_b 
             SHARED   
             ${TFC_Path}/Lib_b/File_c.c
             ${TFC_Path}/Lib_b/File_d.c                                   
             )

#since not all headers are automatically included, though File_a.h was listed in add_library(Lib_a), but Lib_b needs that header i am adding following line:
target_include_directories( TFC_Lib_a PUBLIC ${TFC_Path}/Lib_a) 

target_link_libraries( applications_jni TFC_Lib_b)
target_link_libraries( TFC_Lib_b TFC_Lib_a)
```

**Update**
If i dont include File_a.h in Lib_a the compiler is not complaining, since the header is found through target_include_directories, but when i build the error of missing Lib_a.h remains!

Comment: **Precise** error message, please. You have several libraries and many include directories, so error description `file.h not found` is useless. From the error message it should be known which **exact source file** is failed to compile, and which **exact header file** is not found. Also provide trace of these source and header files to the `CMakeLists.txt`: which *library* uses given source file, and which *include directory* contains given header file.

Comment: `set(TFC_Path C:/Users/<user>/AndroidStudioProjects/TFVC/)` is absolutely one of your problems. You cannot assume anything about the user who will run the build. Your solution must be more solid than that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev when writing so much i always miss something: i updated the tree and specified the file that was not found - it should be clearer now :)

Comment: @LucaCappa I know that i should not work with absolute paths - but i really have no idea how to include the files in my project with relative paths (it is the only way it worked for me by now). Which way should i go to achieve relative paths?

Comment: So, missed header file `File_a.h` is actually located under directory `${TFC_Path}/Lib_a/Source_headers`, which you are included last. Is it right or not? (You use **different naming scheme** in your directory tree and `CMakeLists.txt`, so it is difficult to correlate them.) As for hardcoded path in `TFC_Path`, isn't it should point to the directory where `CMakeLists.txt` is located? If so, you may refer to that directory using automatic variable `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : you are 100% correct! I made some small but important mistakes which makes impossible to understand my issue. Sorry for that, i dont know how it could happen. Now it should be really clearer!! The CmakeLists.txt is in a different directory since i was not able to build the TFS project as a module or include the files in the android project (see 1.). Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved the include problem by adding a "../Lib_a/" before the "File_a.h" include statement. Since there are lots of files in the libraries to adjust and they are from a TFS, so this is not really the answer i was looking for. I thought that after specifying the library dependencies in CMakeLists you could simply include the file. Now: [How to set up CMakeLists to not have to change the include statements from a TFS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495437/set-up-cmakelists-to-not-change-the-include-statements-from-tfs-project-in-andro)!