# Set up CMakeLists to not change the include statements from TFS project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, tfs, cmake, include

From a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454762/howto-tfs-check-out-c-c-source-files-build-libs-through-cmakelists) a new one have arisen. I want to include 2 native TFS project libraries stored in two different folders, dependant from each other in my Android Studio project (stored in another folder). If i not specify "../my_lib_path/libFile.h" instead of simply the "libFile.h" i get the error the file is not found. But i dont want to change all includes since it is a TFS project and there are lots of file contained in the libraries!

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please, describe hierarchy of your project and its `CMakeLists.txt` files (which are related to your problem). And please, do that in **consistent** manner.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev ! The hierarchy and the CMakeLists is still the same as in the previous question (which should be consistent) - that is why i linked it. Thank you for helping here too!

Comment: It is Stack Overflow requirement, that all **important** information about the problem should be **in the question post** itself. You may use links for provide *additional* information though.

Comment: No, you have to change all includes, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Finally i changed the includes like you suggested. By adding proper target_include_directories() i was able to minimize the changes a bit, depending on the folder structure. @Andy-MSFT please summarize that with your comment and i will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory. So you have to specify "../my_lib_path/libFile.h", that means you need to change all includes, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy Li-MSFT is absolutely right! Though what worked for me in a similar project now was to set a different relative CMakeLists.txt path in the app .gradle file outside the specific Android Studio Project directory:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../../whatever_path/my_C_files/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

After that i was able to compile my C sources flawlessly without changing the include paths of the C project!